# Migration Spring Boot 1.X to 2.X remove _class field from BSON Document

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, bson

I recently migrated the Spring Boot version of a project, upgrading from version 1.X to 2.X. However, this caused problems in recovering persisted objects using the `org.bson.Document` (using [`PojoCodecProvider`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/)), because they did not have the `_class` field.

I persist my information as follows (I need to save all my instances to retrieve them later):

```
Map<String, Object> outbound = new HashMap<>();
// Add multiple objects/instances of different types
log.setOutbound(new Document(outbound));
```

Where my `Log` entity/document is essentially like this:

```
public class Log { 
    private ObjectId id;
    private Document outbound;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to recover the persisted objects, converting to their specific types:

```
Log log = this.logRepository.findById("ID_HERE");
Document outbound = lastTracking.getOutbound();
MyType = outbound.get("myTypeKey", MyType.class); //A cast exception occours here!
```

Analyzing the difference between the data saved in the Spring Boot version 1 and 2, I identified that the most current version stopped recording the `_class` field, looking to the instances stored in my `Document` (`Log#outbound`).

Has anyone experienced this problem? Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE:** I created a simple repository that simulates this problem:

https://github.com/falvojr/stackoverflow-61560293

The [Application](https://github.com/falvojr/stackoverflow-61560293/blob/master/src/main/java/com/falvojr/Application.java) class has all the configuration and execution flow, as well as explanatory comments.

Comment: Is the `outbound` field used in `Log` an `org.bson.Document` ? Do you have a piece of code that I can run to see what's going on?

Comment: Hi @ChristophStrobl, thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm using `org.bson.Document`, in addition to `PojoCodecProvider` in my project. I'm sorry for the delay, I was creating a simple project to simulate for you: https://github.com/falvojr/so-question-61560293.

Comment: This looks like you should create a ticket in Spring Boot bug tracker

Comment: This is a Spring Data MongoDB question so asking to create an issue in the Spring Boot issue tracker wasn't a great recommendation. See also [the guidelines for contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc#using-github-issues)